# Generate multiple plots in base R with loop function then concatenate by matching group variables

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, plot

I have a data frame (below, my apologies for the verbose code, this is my first attempt at generating reproducible random data) that I'd like to loop through and generate individual plots in base R (specifically, ethograms) for each subject's day and video clip (e.g. subj-1/day1/clipB). After generating *n* graphs, I'd like to concatenate a PDF for each subj that includes all days + clips, and have each row correspond to a single day. I haven't been able to get past the generating individual graphs, however, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Data frame**

```
n <- 20000

library(stringi)

test <- as.data.frame(sprintf("%s", stri_rand_strings(n, 2, '[A-Z]')))

colnames(test)<-c("Subj")

test$Day <- sample(1:3, size=length(test$Subj), replace=TRUE)

test$Time <- sample(0:600, size=length(test$Subj), replace=TRUE)

test$Behavior <- as.factor(sample(c("peck", "eat", "drink", "fly", "sleep"), size = length(test$Time), replace=TRUE))

test$Vid_Clip <- sample(c("Clip_A", "Clip_B", "Clip_C"), size = length(test$Time), replace=TRUE)
```

**Sample data from data frame:**

```
> head(test)
  Subj Day Time Behavior Vid_Clip
1   BX   1  257    drink   Clip_B
2   NP   2  206    sleep   Clip_B
3   ZF   1  278     peck   Clip_B
4   MF   2  391    sleep   Clip_A
5   VE   1  253      fly   Clip_C
6   ID   2  359      eat   Clip_C
```

After adapting [this code](https://github.com/idworkin/ethograms/blob/master/ethogramScript.R), I am able to successfully generate a single plot (one at a time):

**Subset single subj/day/clip:**

```
single_subj_day_clip <- test[test$Vid_Clip == "Clip_B" & test$Subj == "AA" & test$Day == 1,]
```

After which, I can generate the graph I'm after by running the following lines:

```
beh_numb <- nlevels(single_subj_day_clip$Behavior)

mar.default <- c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1
par(mar = mar.default + c(0, 4, 0, 0))
plot(single_subj_day_clip$Time, 
     xlim=c(0,max(single_subj_day_clip$Time)), ylim=c(0, beh_numb), type="n",
     ann=F, yaxt="n", frame.plot=F)

for (i in 1:length(single_subj_day_clip$Behavior))  {
  ytop <- as.numeric(single_subj_day_clip$Behavior[i])
  ybottom <- ytop - 0.5
  rect(xleft=single_subj_day_clip$Subj[i], xright=single_subj_day_clip$Time[i+1],
       ybottom=ybottom, ytop=ytop, col = ybottom)}

axis(side=2, at = (1:beh_numb -0.25), labels=levels(single_subj_day_clip$Behavior), las = 1) 
mtext(text="Time (sec)", side=1, line=3, las=1)
```

**[Example graph from randomly generate data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88WM1.png)**(sorry for link - newb SO user so until I'm at 10 reputation pts, I can't embed an image directly)

[**Example graph from actual data**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q60nO.png)

[**Ideal per subject graph**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNeoA.png)

Thank you all in advance for your input.

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New and hopefully correct answer

The code is too long to post it here, so [there is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zt9su7a786tb461/AABiAm4WOst2OrxI1tMEjcARa?dl=0) to the Dropbox folder with data and code. You can check [this html document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pg5m8yrxp6j33g2/ethogRam.html?dl=0) or run [this .Rmd file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/clqg0ogrmmkjrnn/ethogRam.Rmd?dl=0) on your machine. Please check if all required packages are installed. There is [the output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sqhr0druobf755k/ethogram.pdf?dl=0) of the script.

There are additional problem in the analysis - some events are registered only once, at a single time point between other events. So there is no "width" of such bars. I assigned width of such events to 1000 ms, so some (around 100 per 20000 observations) of them are out of scale if they are at the beginning or at the end of the experiment (and **if** the width for such events is equal to zero). You can play with the code to fix this behavior.

Another problem is the different colors for the same factors on the different plots. I need some fresh air to fix it as well.

Looking into the graphs, you can notice that sometimes, it seems that some observation with a very short time are overlapping with other observations. But if you zoom the pdf to the maximum - you will see that they are not, and there is a 'holes' in underlying intervals, where they are supposed to be.

Lines, connecting the intervals for different kinds of behavior are helping to follow the timecourse of the experiment. You can uncomment corresponding parts of the code, if you wish.

Please let me know if it works.

### Old answer

I am not sure it is the best way to do it, but probably you can use `split()` and after that `lapply` through your tables:

#### Split your data.frame by `Subj`, `Day`, and `Vid_clip`:

```
testl <- split(test, test[, c(1, 2, 5)], drop = T)

testl[[1123]]
#      Subj Day Time Behavior Vid_Clip
#8220    ST   2  303      fly   Clip_A
#9466    ST   2  463      fly   Clip_A
#9604    ST   2   32     peck   Clip_A
#10659   ST   2  136     peck   Clip_A
#13126   ST   2   47      fly   Clip_A
#14458   ST   2  544     peck   Clip_A
```

#### Loop through the list with your data and plot to .pdf:

```
mar.default <- c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1
par(mar = mar.default + c(0, 4, 0, 0))

nbeh = nlevels(test$Behavior)

pdf("plots.pdf")
invisible(
  lapply(testl, function(l){
    plot(x = l$Time, xlim = c(0, max(l$Time)), ylim = c(0, nbeh),
         type = "n", ann = F, yaxt = "n", frame.plot = F)
    lapply(1:nbeh, function(i){
      ytop <- as.numeric(l$Behavior[i]); ybot <- ytop - .5
      rect(l$Subj[i], ybot, l$Time[i + 1], ytop, col = ybot)
    })
    axis(side = 2, at = 1:nbeh - .25, labels = levels(l$Behavior), las = 1)
    mtext(text = "Time (sec)", side = 1, line = 3, las = 1)
  })
  )
dev.off()
```

You should probably check [output here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bh6a1hjqcc7zy6j/plots.pdf?dl=0) before you run code on your PC. I didn't edit much your plot-code, so please check it twice.

Comment: Thanks @utubun. This definitely helps! My main issue though is the graph doesn't take into account multiple behaviors at multiple time points any more...  Here's what [my actual data looks like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/egyerngndtydwrw/plots.pdf?dl=0). Any thoughts?  (thanks again for your help :) !).

Comment: Additionally, I get this (seemingly) odd output with both my own data and the example data, after running `lapply`: 

$NQ.2.Clip_A
NULL

$NR.2.Clip_A
NULL

$NS.2.Clip_A
NULL

$NT.2.Clip_A
NULL

$NU.2.Clip_A
NULL

Comment: Ah, my mistake, you need to delete `nbeh = nlevels(l$Behavior)` form `lapply` body and before `lapply` add `nbeh = nlevels(test$Behavior)` so it must solve the problem. Output are values returned by `lapply`, you can ignore it, or, you can make it `invisible`. I will edit my post.

Comment: @Dan try edited code. I also noticed there are some odd vertical lines which divide some bars, so probably check if everything is ok at the code associated with plots.

Comment: thank you for the insight. Yes - that definitely improves it! My only hang up (and this is likely my lack of understanding the source plotting code, which is not my own) is why the behavior cuts off. For my actual data, there's behavior across the entire 600 s period, but the graphs in the loop function (but not if done on an individual basis) don't capture that. If you have the time or interest, here is [my actual data and code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4vsdkhlfci6z3tk/AADVC_9p-QEgoFQfW9vXmRIya?dl=0) I'm trying to run. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: For a comparison, [here's](https://imgur.com/a/wMNarKc) the graph I get if I make them one at a time vs with `lapply`...wonky stuff!

Comment: Ok, it takes some time to understand the problem, but I am quite positive about it. And is it really critical for you to build base plots? I mean what if you can do the same in `ggplot`? If you are ok with it, I will copy your data to my dropbox, and after that I'll send you a link.

Comment: Sure! That'd be tremendously helpful. I'm not married to base plots, so any attempt w/ `ggplot` would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @Dan, I prepared [dummy data set](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cma1ys2wuxsv574/AAAOn3wr5YEf8gUxSI2jWiywa?dl=0), to check if everything works fine, and there are no mistakes on the plot. Please have a look at the graph and csv file. I connected bars by dotted lines to follow the time and direction of changes in activity. Please check it out and let me know what do you think. Probably email would be more appropriate (you can find it on profile page).

Comment: I'm unable to find your email address (maybe as a new user it's not visible to me)? But either way, thank you for taking the time to tinker w/ the code! It looks great! Maybe I could grab it from a Dropbox link? Thanks :)

Comment: Hey @Dan, I have updated my answer. Please follow the links and let me know if it is what you expect it to be

Comment: Hi @utubun - this is perfect! I do hope you publish this somewhere as JWatcher is a convenient open-source behavior software and this would dramatically improve output for most users IMHO. I'm not sure how to message you privately about minor edits or suggestions, but overall it worked perfectly for me and is precisely what I was looking for :) Thank you for all your time and work with this - I've learned a lot!!

Comment: Hey @Dan, I am glad it helped you in your work. Actually thanks to you, I discovered ethograms - I had no idea such amazing things exist. I still have an interest to work on it. But what I really need is someone who is experienced in the field, and who can say what is required and how it must look like. I really have a lot of questions about different data formats, experimental approaches, which kind of conclusions someone can make from the data etc. You can wright me on yahoo mail, with the same name as here. Hope I can do all the edits you mentioned.